# Using multiple conditions in NewApi with Python

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I'm tryin to run the following code

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd 
import nltk 
from newspaper import Article
import re

newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key = 'myKey')

data = newsapi.get_everything(q = "(loan OR draw down OR credit line OR credit facility " \
                                "OR borrow OR syndicated loan) AND " \
                                "(Barclays  OR Citi OR  JPMorgan OR " \
                                "Bank of America OR Wells Fargo OR Intesa OR"\
                                "Unicredit OR Nordea OR BBVA OR Santander OR"\
                                "Credit Agricole OR BPCE OR Goldman Sachs OR"\
                                "Royal Bank of Scotland OR HSBC OR Mizhuo OR"\
                                "Sumitomo OR Deutsche Bank OR BNP OR Royal bank of Canada OR"\
                                "ING)", 
                          language = 'en', page_size = 20, 
                          from_param= "2020-03-01", sort_by = "relevancy",
                          sources = 'reuters')
```

It works up the third row of OR conditions after which the number of articles retrieved starts to decline (which I would not expect given that it is an OR condition?) and by running the full command I get an empty list which is not the case if I run only the first two rows of OR conditions.

Anyone with similar experiences?

Comment: I have been testing this, seems there are some odd criteria on the query string which make the results confusing. I haven't yet managed to figure out what is happening...